# R density plot y axis larger than 1

Tags: r, density-plot

I want a density plot, and here is the code:

```
d = as.matrix(read.csv(file = '1.csv'))
plot(density(d))
```

my data is a list of number. What I don't understand is that the value of y axis large than 1
I think there is something wrong and search the internet, but i can't find any resource, Can you guys help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3wVR.png)
here is the data:
link：http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hsE8Ony password：7a4z

Comment: Please post what you data looks like.

Comment: data has been upload, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing wrong with the density being greater than 1 at some points.  The area under the curve must be 1, but at specific points the density can be greater than 1. For example,

```
dnorm(0,0, 0.1)
[1] 3.989423
```

See this [Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok)

**Edit:**
I think that the `dnorm` part above could be amplified a little.

For a Gaussian distribution, with mean μ and standard deviation σ approximately 99.73% of the area under the density curve lies between
μ-3σ and μ+3σ. The example above used μ=0 and σ=0.1 so the area under the curve between -0.3 and 0.3 should be 0.9973. The width of the curve here is 0.6. Compare this with a rectangle of equal area (0.9973) and the same base (0.6).

[image: Gaussian Distribution]

If the area of the rectangle is 0.9973 and the base is 0.6, the height must be 0.9973/0.6 = 1.6621,  i.e. the average height of the curve must be 1.6621. Clearly there must be *some* points with height greater than 1.

Comment: Is there a way to change the Y axis of density to probability? Thanks